# Styling words in textarea element differently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a spell checker that marks incorrectly spelled words in red. To do this, I am using a Trie to store the words in a text file I have on my local server in Node.js. There is a textarea element for users to enter words. When they press space or enter, I want to take the text they typed, process it, and update the text with incorrectly spelled words underlined in red.

I know the CSS text-decoration property can be used for underlining all text in an element, but I am not sure how to underline only some words. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need to use a `contenteditable` element instead of a `<textarea>`.

Comment: easier doable with another container such as a `div` with `contenteditable` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `contenteditable` attribute to use `div` like `textarea`.
here is example.

```js
document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = '<span style="color: red">bb</span>a'
```

```html
<div id="area" contenteditable="true"></div>
```